# How to determine if the current application is Medium Trust

Tags: c#, asp.net, medium-trust

I am trying to make sure my ASP.Net library will work under Medium Trust. I'm having problems however in that I need to disable a bit of code if it is being run under medium trust.

How do I determine from C# if the current application is medium trust?

Specifically, I'm trying to read the customErrors section from web.config and I'm getting security errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article here describes a mechanism to determine the trust level:

> [Finding out the current trust level in ASP.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/23/finding-out-the-current-trust-level-in-asp-net.aspx)

Here is the code just in case the link dies:

```
AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetCurrentTrustLevel() {
  foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in
      new AspNetHostingPermissionLevel [] {
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted,
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High,
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium,
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low,
        AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal 
      } ) {
    try {
      new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException ) {
      continue;
    }

    return trustLevel;
   }

   return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}
```

I just tested it in an ASP.NET MVC3 application running at Medium and then Full trust and it does what it says on the tin.

Comment: I guess if you're only doing it once at `Application_Start` time then it's not a huge thing in the great scheme of things. The problem is that the less Trust you have then the less things you can try and this is the one thing that's left that you can try under all trust levels.